# Past Perfect Sentence structure for yes/no questions

Tags: past-perfect

Which of these is correct and why?

1. Had not you seen this movie before?
2. Had you not seen this movie before?

Comment: what about "didn't you watch/see this movie before"? any other tense sounds... I don't know, medieval?

Comment: But is either of the above right/ wrong?

Comment: In real life, it would probably be just "Hadn't you seen ..". those two examples sound extremely archaic at best.

Comment: The "had" tense is fine if the parties have just watched the movie in question.

Comment: They are both grammatical; however, the first version is not normal. It's both archaic and poetic. The second version, while not as common as other ways of writing it, is at least modern—and fine in certain contexts.